# Google Talk App Specific Passwords in Empathy

Tags: 12.10, empathy

I have been using App Specific Passwords in Google for a while and recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10.  Since then, I have been unable to get Empathy working with Google Talk.  Is there a way to get it working?

Thanks!

Comment: DId you input the Google app specific password in Empathy, not your Google account's password.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

In Empathy, there are two types of accounts that I could add: Jabber or Google.

If I add the Jabber account, I can't get it working either with my regular gmail password or with my application specific password.  When it tries to connect, it just hangs.

If I add the Google account, it prompts me to login to my Google account by opening an embedded browser window.  If I try to put in an app specific password, it tells me to use my regular password.  When I use my regular password, it prompts me for a two factor authentication.  I had assumed that that wasn't what it should do, thinking that it would then have to prompt me each time I logged in to my computer, but I can see that Ubuntu is authorized in my Google account menu now, which should work.

In other words, Empathy doesn't work with app specific passwords because it doesn't need to use app specific passwords.

I am still unsure, however, why it didn't work with Jabber in general.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed up the problem.
Now I can access google talk behind my corporate firewall.

As root edit the file /`usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service`

1) change the line:

```
  <setting name="param-server">talk.google.com</setting>
  to
  <setting name="param-server">talk.google.com:443</setting>
```

2) Add the line:

```
   <setting name="param-old-ssl">true</setting>
```

(There is a list of backup servers in this file, but I couldn't make those work like you would expect)

reboot  (probably something else you can restart to make these changes work, but this is sure fire).

Start empathy (assuming you already have a google account created).  No need for a jabber account. It looks like it tries to login twice, the second time works (no clue why that is).

Hope that helps.